# How could I get custom material for custom mesh

Tags: three.js

I would like to draw a house.
I'm new to three.js
I know how to draw cubes (walls) 
but how best to draw the roof? And especially the section of the wall directly under the peak of the roof? 
I know of such a method:

```
var starPoints = [];

starPoints.push(new THREE.Vector2(-500, 0));
starPoints.push(new THREE.Vector2(0, 500));
starPoints.push(new THREE.Vector2(500, 0));

var starShape = new THREE.Shape(starPoints);

var extrusionSettings = {
    size: 0, height: 0, curveSegments: 0,
    bevelThickness: 0, bevelSize: 0, bevelEnabled: false,
    material: 0
    , extrudeMaterial: 1
    , amount: 100
};

var starGeometry = new THREE.ExtrudeGeometry(starShape, extrusionSettings);

var materialFront = get_material(gparams.kirpich, 1, 1); //materials_list.basic_color; // new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ color: 0xffff00 });
var materialSide = get_material(gparams.kirpich, 1, 1);
var materialSide2 = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ color: "#f00" });
var materialArray = [materialFront, materialSide];
var starMaterial = new THREE.MeshFaceMaterial(materialArray);


var star = new THREE.Mesh(starGeometry, materialFront);
star.position.set(0, 250, 0);
//star.rotation.x = -90 * Math.PI / 180;

scene.add(star);
```

I have got a triange, but I can not get necessary material for this triangle.
I can get only color material, but I want to get custom material from a material picture.
How could I get necessary material or may be there is another way to get custom mesh with custom material for these purpose?

Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want to use `loadTexture` which you can use to load an image onto your mesh.

```
texture = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture(<your image>);
material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({map: texture});
```

See some examples [here](http://stemkoski.github.io/Three.js/Textures.html), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7927289/746754), [here](http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/three/html5-canvas-webgl-texture-with-three-js/) and [here](http://solutiondesign.com/webgl-and-three-js-texture-mapping/).

**Update (see comments)**

To change a texture, keep a copy of the mesh, then change the texture and set `needsUpdate` to true on the texture. Finally, set texture on material map. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18436431/746754) and code below:

```
 function setTextureImage( imageSrc )
 {         
     texture = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture(<your imageSrc>);
     texture.needsUpdate = true;
     m_modelMesh.material.map = texture;         
 }
```

Comment: Thank you very much! 
Now it's all right.
Could you please help to understand how to change material by a mouse click?

Comment: @user3527449 - glad to help. See the update. Please upvote or accept the answer if it is helpful to you.