# How can three.js object be updated with click?

Tags: javascript, jquery, three.js

How can properties of a three.js object be updated via interaction--specifically a click? For example, how can I toggle the wireframe off when an svg is selected?

I have read the three.js docs on [How to Update Things](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#manual/introduction/How-to-update-things) as well as the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18436431/three-js-update-texture-image) which I'm struggling to pull together to answer my own.

Here's the [codepen](https://codepen.io/peakera/pen/djVLoZ) and the code:

```
var container, camera, scene, renderer, geometry, cylinder1, material1, mesh1, stats;

function init() {

  container = document.getElementById( 'canvas' );
    scene = new THREE.Scene();
    camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(50, window.innerWidth/window.innerHeight, 1, 10000);
    camera.position.z = 1000;
  scene.add(camera);

  var axis = new THREE.Vector3(1, 0, 0);
  var rad = THREE.Math.degToRad(90);
  var axesHelper = new THREE.AxesHelper( 500 );
  scene.add( axesHelper );

  cylinder1 = new THREE.CylinderGeometry(275, 275, 50, 100);
    material1 = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( {color: 'blue', wireframe: true} );
    mesh1 = new THREE.Mesh(cylinder1, material1);
  mesh1.rotateOnAxis(axis, rad);
  mesh1.position.set(0,0,25);
    scene.add(mesh1);
  mesh1.material.needsUpdate = true;


  $("#maj1").focus( function() {
    material1 = THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( {wireframe: false });
  })

    renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({alpha: true});
    renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
    document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

  stats = new Stats();
  stats.showPanel( 1, 2 );
  document.body.appendChild( stats.domElement );


    animate();

} init();

function animate() {
    requestAnimationFrame(animate); 
        renderer.render(scene, camera);

}
```

Running that code returns:

> three.min.js:24 Uncaught TypeError: this.setValues is not a function
>       at Object.ua [as MeshBasicMaterial] (three.min.js:24)
>       at SVGSVGElement. (pen.js:26)
>       at SVGSVGElement.dispatch (jquery.min.js:2)
>       at SVGSVGElement.y.handle (jquery.min.js:2)

I know I'm likely getting both the update call and its placement wrong...

Comment: `material1 = THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( {wireframe: false });` should be like `material1.wireframe = false;`

Comment: Is the mesh1.material.needsUpdate = true; still needed? If not, why? Thanks so much!

Comment: it should work without setting `.needsUpdate` to `true`.